# Pandas reset_index() error ValueError: cannot insert Country, already exists

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
Date    Province    Country Confirmed   Deaths  Recovered
0   2020-01-22  Anhui   Mainland China  1.0 0.0 0.0
1   2020-01-22  Beijing Mainland China  14.0    0.0 0.0
2   2020-01-22  Chongqing   Mainland China  6.0 0.0 0.0
3   2020-01-22  Fujian  Mainland China  1.0 0.0 0.0
4   2020-01-22  Gansu   Mainland China  0.0 0.0 0.0
```

```
df2 = df.groupby('Country')[['Country','Confirmed','Deaths','Recovered']].sum().reset_index()
```

```
ValueError: cannot insert Country, already exists
```

I want to see groupby `Country`

Comment: Grouping by Country sets it as index. You can't ask to view it as a column right up. Reset the index before, not after.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `Country` from column spec:

```py
df2 = df.groupby("Country")[["Confirmed", "Deaths", "Recovered"]].sum().reset_index()

print(df2)
```

Prints:

```
          Country  Confirmed  Deaths  Recovered
0  Mainland China       22.0     0.0        0.0
```

Comment: It worked, I just removed 'Country', thank you.